How update Car Screen with onNewIntent session method
I am currently sending a CarPendingIntent from a notification action.
Intent responseIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CarAppService.class);
        responseIntent.putExtra(CarAppSession.ITEM_ID, itemID);
        responseIntent.putExtra(CarAppSession.USER_ID, userID);

        int flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;

        PendingIntent carResponsePendingIntent = CarPendingIntent.getCarApp(
                getApplicationContext(),
                0, //Request Code but idk which is its use
                responseIntent,
                flags
        );

        CarAppExtender.Builder cae = new CarAppExtender.Builder();
        cae.setContentTitle(type);
        cae.setContentText(message);
        cae.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        cae.addAction(
                R.drawable.open_icon,
                getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.open),
                carResponsePendingIntent
        );


        // Add extender to notification builder
        notificationBuilder.extend(cae.build());

I am receiving the intent in the onNewIntent method of my Session, but I want to open a specific screen in response. However, the screenManager cannot be accessed from this method. How can I change the current screen to the new one?
Also, I am not sure if this approach is possible or recommended.
Here onNewIntent method (The logic to change the screen, update, or navigate is missing, which is the part I'm not quite sure how to implement)
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)

    val itemId = intent.getStringExtra(ITEM_ID)
    val userId = intent.getStringExtra(USER_ID)

    val itemDetailScreen = itemDetailScreen(carContext, userId, itemId)
   
}

I also see in the documentation related to this method that it is used to update the information or change the current screen in the stack.
